# How to receive a value in a variable sent from the client with ajax in a URL in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I have a `URL` which I want to `send` to the `server` with `ajax` in order to `delete` products based on `id`. How can I `receive` that with `NodeJS` just as I would do this in the `PHP api` so :

```
$sProductId = $_GET['id'];
```

This is the URL from the ajax call:

```
var sUrl = "/delete-product" + sProductId;
```

This is my server.js

```
app.post('/delete-product' ???, upload.none(), (req, res) => {
        global.sUpdateProductImagePath = req.file.path.split("public/")[req.file.path.split("public").length - 1]
        user.deleteProduct(req.body, (err, jResult) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(jResult)
                return res.send(jResult)
            }
            console.log(jResult)
            return res.send(jResult)

        })
    })
```

And my user.js:

```
user.deleteProduct = (jProductData, fCallback) => {
    global.db.collection('products').deleteOne({ "_id": "" }, (err, jResult) => {
        if (err) {
            var jError = { "status": "error", "message": "ERROR -> deleteProduct -> user.js -> 001" }
            return fCallback(false, jError)
        }
        var jOk = { "status": "ok", "message": "user.js -> product deleted -> 000" }
        console.log(jResult)
        return fCallback(false, jOk)
    })
}
```

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this if you want id in path params

```
app.post('/delete-product/:id', upload.none(), (req, res) => {var id= req.params.id; // this id is from path params
```

you can also send id in search query like /delete-product?id=yourid

```
 app.post('/delete-product', upload.none(), (req, res) => {var id= req.query.id;
```

Comment: how would my URL on the client would look like if  I use path params just like this? `"/delete-product" + sProductId`or? I used the query way and it worked. thank´s.  I am just curious.

Comment: for path params it would be like "/delete-product/ +sProductId" eg: /delete-product/12663

Answer (score 0):

The way you are passing the parameters to send it from the client to the server is a get method. The id is part of the url.

So, in the server you should change the post for get and add /:idproduct to receive it.

Also, instead of req.body, you should change to req.params.:

For example:

app.get('/delete-product/:idproduct', (req, res) => {

```
    //global.sUpdateProductImagePath = req.file.path.split("public/")[req.file.path.split("public").length - 1]
    //req.body = req.params.idproduct
    user.deleteProduct(req.params.idproduct, (err, jResult) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(jResult)
            return res.send(jResult)
        }
        console.log(jResult)
        return res.send(jResult)

    })
})
```